# For First Student In Time Insert In Table After That For Another Student Only Else Condition Executed. So help me for this.

Tags: php, mysqli

In my page there are 2 values which is employee id and type, inside type in and out is there. if student select in so value inserted in in time in mysql and if student select out so value inserted in out time column. But in my case not this happended. In time only inserted for student id 1 after that whenever i select in time for any student it will goes in else part and show me already added. Out time updated for everyone but in time is not inserted for everyone so help me for this.

```
<?php 
session_start();
$branch=$_SESSION['branch'];
include('../dist/includes/dbcon.php');

    $emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    //echo $type;

        $query2=mysqli_query($con,"select in_time,emp_id from emp_a")or die(mysqli_error($con));
        //$count=mysqli_num_rows($query2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
        {
        $in = $row['in_time'];
        $id = $row['emp_id'];
        }
        //echo $in;
        if($type == 'In' && is_null($in))
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO emp_a(emp_id,att_date,in_time,status) VALUES('$emp_id',curdate(),now(),1)")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Successfully added time log!');</script>";
        }
        elseif($type == 'Out')
        {
            mysqli_query($con,"update emp_a set out_time = now(),status = 1 where emp_id = '$emp_id' and att_date=curdate()")or die(mysqli_error($con));
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Leaving Time added!');</script>";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No!');</script>";
        }
                              echo "<script>document.location='home.php'</script>";  



?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to do, but `$in` and `$id` will always have the last record returned from the select query

Comment: i want to add entry time and exist time for every student so for that i made html and php page that will shown student name and in and out type if student select in time so insert query would be perfomed and if type is out so update query for out time. But in my case only for first student it was performed after that for another student it goes in else part and shown me No statement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `$emp_id` in order to get `in_time`, `out_time` for perticular employee, currently it gives in and out time for all the employees and get the last employee detail from the while loop.

```
 $query2=mysqli_query($con,"select in_time,emp_id from emp_a where emp_id='$emp_id'")or die(mysqli_error($con));
    //$count=mysqli_num_rows($query2);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
    {
    $in = $row['in_time'];
    $id = $row['emp_id'];
    }
```